# Why I am getting: Undefined subroutine

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I am trying to move existing perl files to a new server and I am getting an error (error_log file). It work on the old server.

When I access to: http://2x.29.xx.xx/admin/web.pl

I get an error:

> [error] Undefined subroutine &web_main::main called at
>   /var/www/path/web.pl line 40.

**web.pl** file, it look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/var/www/web';

our $var = '/var/www/web';
our $var1; 
our $var2; 
use web_main qw($var $var1 $var2);

web_main::main();  # Line 40
```

**web_main.pm** file (in /var/www/web), look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

package web_main;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub main
{

  # Lots of code here... removed for brevity
}
```

Not sure what went wrong?

Comment: I think you need to `use web_main;` as well in web.pl

Comment: You will not get that error from that code.

Comment: @squiguy, No, he's is loading web_main.

Comment: Note that `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` makes no sense in a module, and it will be completely ignored as a comment.

Comment: Make sure that when you're running your web.pl, you're in a folder that '/var/www/web' is in. Because maybe you're in another folder that the one in 'use lib' isn't able to find.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really an expert in Perl but perhaps you need to export the main subroutine? You can use [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).